# What's the difference between "we have grown to be" and "we have grown to become"?

Tags: word-choice, difference, verbs

When I google "we have grown to be" and "we have grown to become" respectively, I get a decent number of hits for both (22 pages and 24 pages respectively, set to UK pages only), which suggests that both are correct – but what is the difference between them? When I look at the hits I get, it seems they are interchangeable – is this so?

Comment: Young people who had enjoyed early success might reflect that they had **grown to become** leaders in their field.  Many years later they might reflect that they had **grown to be**. Choose whichever you think fits the context better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that these phrases are highly interchangeable.

To be technical, I think "to be" generally refers to a *current status*. In example,

> "we have grown to be great entrepreneurs"

On the other hand, "to become", may refer to a sort of *transformation*,

> "through our entrepreneurship we have grown to become quite wealthy"

It's basically the same thing, but that example may illustrate the slight difference.